# Maximum possible gcd of integer elements, whose sum is 540.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

What would be a maximum possible GCD of $a_1, a_2, ... a_{49} \in  \mathbb{N}$ . Given that

$$
a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_{49} =540
$$

The answer from the book is 10. I was trying to solve it using linear combinations of GCD. However, I stuck.

Comment: Are $a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_{49}$ positive integers?

Comment: yes, they are. Sorry, I'll update the text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{49})=(db_1,db_2,\ldots,db_{49})$, where $d=\gcd(a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_{49})$.

$$b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_{49}=\frac{540}{d}\ge 1+1+\cdots+1=49$$ Therefore $d\le 11$. We can't have $d=11$, because $11\nmid 540$. However,

$$(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{49})=(\underbrace{10,10,\ldots,10}_{48 \text{ numbers}},60)$$

works as a solution, so $d=10$ is the maximum possible value of $d$.

Answer (score 1):

If $gcd(a_1,a_2,...,a_{49})$ would be at least $12$, the sum would be at least
$588$, which would be too big. If the gcd would be $11$, we would get the
equation $11k=540$, which has no solution.

It is easy to find a solution with $gcd(a_1,a_2,...a_{49})=10$.